# tornado 4.5 application.named_handlers gone

Tags: python, tornado

with upgrading to 4.5 an Attribute Error occurs when accessing `named_handlers` from within `tornado.web.RequestHandler`

```
 AttributeError: 'Application' object has no attribute 'named_handlers'
```

What is the new way getting the list/dictionary of named_handlers?

Answer (score 1):

This was removed as part of the new [flexible routing](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/releases/v4.5.0.html#new-module) feature. Try the [reverse_url](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.reverse_url) function, which is still available in Tornado 4.5.

```
handler = application.reverse_url('name')
```

Comment: works, thx. It seems that ```application.wildcard_router.named_rules``` is the old ```named_handlers```, isn't it?

Comment: More or less, but with the new architecture there may be many routers. Rely on "reverse_url" instead of "named_rules", since the former is documented and stable and won't change again in the next release.

Comment: i used it for getting all registered handlers for a kind of an *"OverviewHandler"*, is there another way getting all registered handlers?